# Change a text in files in a folder next to string "Text_ID"

Tags: c#, streamreader

Example of a text file below

> text_file a
>
> Text_ID "441124_aad0656_1234"
>
> Text_FILE_NAME

I would like to keep only last index of string "1234"

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(text);
string text2;
while ((text2 = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    num++;
    string[] array3 = text2.Split(new char[0]);
    if (array3[0] == "Text_ID")
    {
        string[] array4 = array3[1].Split(new char[] {'_'});
        string value = "Text_ID" + " " + '"' + array4[1];
        streamWriter.WriteLine(value);
    }
    else
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(text2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `File.ReadAllLines` to read the file into an array, then search through the array for the line you want to change, replace that line with the new string, and then use `File.WriteAllLines` to write the array back to the file:

```
var filePath = @"f:\public\temp\temp.txt";

// The string to search for
var searchTxt = "Text_ID";

// Read all the lines of the file into an array
var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

// Loop through each line in the array
for(int i = 0; i < fileLines.Length; i++)
{
    // Check if the line begins with our search term
    if (fileLines[i].Trim().StartsWith(searchTxt, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // Get the end of the line, after the last underscore
        var lastPartOfLine = fileLines[i].Substring(fileLines[i].LastIndexOf("_") + 1);

        // Combine our search string, a quote, and the end of the line
        fileLines[i] = $"{searchTxt} \"{lastPartOfLine}";

        // We found what we were looking for, so we can exit the for loop now
        // Remove this line if you expect to find more than one match
        break;
    }
}

// Write the lines back to the file
File.WriteAllLines(filePath, fileLines);
```

If you only want to save the last four lines of the file, you can call `Skip` and pass in the `Length` of the array minus the number of lines you want to keep. This skips all the entries up to the number that you want to save:

```
// Read all the lines of the file into an array
var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

// Take only the last 4 lines
fileLines = fileLines.Skip(fileLines.Length - 4).ToArray();
```

Comment: I have many text files in folder. If I want select only last 4 strings in array

Comment: Thanks it's working but if I want only last 4 strings in the array. Please suggest

Comment: Do you mean you only want to write the last four lines of the `fileLines` array to the file? If so, I've added an example at the bottom of my answer for how to do that. if that's not what you're looking for, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

try below code, and hope it should work for you.

```
 var startsWith = "Text_ID";

 var allLines = File.ReadAllLines("a.txt").ToList();
 allLines = allLines.Select(ln =>
 {
     if(ln.StartsWith(startsWith))
     {
         var finalValue = ln.Split(' ')[1].Trim('"').Split('_').Last();
         //get update line
         return string.Format("{0} \"{1}\"", startsWith, finalValue);
     }
     return ln;
 }).ToList();

 //Write back to file.
 File.WriteAllLines("a.txt", allLines.ToArray());
```

Content before code execution.

```
Record 1
Text_ID "441124_aad0656_1234"
other content.
Record 2
Text_ID "Deepak_Sharma"
other content for line 2
```

Content in file after execution.

```
Record 1
Text_ID "1234"
other content.
Record 2
Text_ID "Sharma"
other content for line 2
```